# Typescript: omit that equals to empty for identical types

Tags: typescript, generics

I got stuck trying to implement generic type that behave the following way:

1. if target type is wider than the source type then result type contains all properties of target type that are not presented in source
2. if target type has identical properties to source then result should be an empty (allow only empty object).

The first condition above seems to be easy implemented like:

```js
// S - stands for Source type
// T - stands for Target type that could be wider
type DiffType<S, T> = Omit<T, keyof S>;
```

but it doesn't satisfy the second condition, assume that:

```js
type A = { a: string; }
type A1 = { a: string; }
type AB = { a: string; b: string; }

// works as expected
const x: DiffType<AB, A> = {
    b: 'b'
}

// unfortunately it doesn't throw error
const x1: DiffType<A, A1> = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

// but should allow only (the desired behavior)
const x2: DiffType<A, A1> = {}
```

I've tried to do something like, but it doesn't help too:

```js
type DiffType<S, T> = {} extends Omit<T, keyof S> ? {} : Omit<T, keyof S>;
```

Could someone advice how to implement such behavior? I hope it's possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Unfortunately it seems to be pretty easy only when you've found the answer! :(

```js
type DiffType<S, T> = {} extends Omit<T, keyof S>
    ? { [K: string]: never }
    : Omit<T, keyof S>;
```

It was necessary to deny adding any key in object manually by `[K: string]: never`. Don't underestimate the power of 'never'!